# Empty test suite error : Writing Instrumentation test cases for android

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I am following the steps exactly as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html) to create instrumentation unit test cases. This is my Test class in the `androidTest->Java->com.mypackage.name` package

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@SmallTest
public class Test {

  private List<String> list;
  @Before
  public void initList(){
    list = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  @org.junit.Test
  public void searchPlace() {
    assert list.size() == 0;

  }
}
```

But when I execute this test case, I get a message saying

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "com.package.base.Test"Empty test suite.
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Normally, cleaning project and trying again works.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error when the test instrumentation runner isn't set correctly. It should be set to `android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner` in the build file. Also double-check the class package name is correct in the test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you Cut-Paste the test from Unit to Instrumental.
Simply goto Main menu -> Run -> Debug -> Edit config...
Delete old and broken tests.
And re-run.